Horizontal Scrollview with adjustable cards
I am trying to do something that seems to not be able to work but I need confirmation.
The behavior that the design team wants is as follows:
We have an horizontal Scrollview that contains a LazyHStack. In this LazyHStack we render an array of components (Views) that contains other sub components such as texts, images, buttons. In fact we render cards elements in a Scrollview.
The height of a card is based on his content (sub components) and can have various heights. Text on multiple line or juste one line, button or not etc. The Scrollview height must match the highest card. When it's done all other cards that are smaller than the bigger one must match the same height. This is where it's weird. Is it possible? If I do so I will be in an infinite loop because, modifying a card height will trigger the height change that I'm listening and will then update Scrollview height, etc., no?
I tried to represent, first image is during the first render, then what we want to have based on the highest Card

Following is some code I used to try to listen to height on a card to set ScrollView height:
public var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        LazyHStack(spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(0..<model.models.count) { index in
                CardView(model: model.models[index])
                    .frame(width: 256)
                    .readHeight()
                    .onHeightChange(perform: {
                        self.updateHeight(height: $0)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
    .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
    .safeAreaPadding(.horizontal, 16)
    .frame(height: height)
    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 0, bottom: 8, trailing: 0))
}

private func updateHeight(height: CGFloat) {
    if height > self.height {
        self.height = height
    }
}

There is already a problem here because the height I get is not the good one. For example, Text can have max 3 lines, and if I have a Text on two lines it will always give the size like Text is on 3 lines. I don't know why but well after that how can I update the card height based on the biggest height? I cannot set directly the frame height because in this case I must define a initial height like 1 for example then I cannot listen on the height anymore. I could pass the height to the Card so it updates the height inside the Card but then I get an infinite loop, no?

The behaviour can be achieved with HStack. Don't know why LazyHStack doesn't work like this but for small collection, HStack fit my needs
